# Extract specific rows from a file depending on some condition ( Command Line )

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I have some content in a file ( which is actually a huge file ) as shown below, is there any way i can **extract rows** which have **lastAccessed value** more than certain value ( say 1464682814617 ) through **command line**.

```
"url":"https://www.google.co.in/","title":"Google","lastAccessed":1464675219253,"hidden":false,""
"url":"https://www.google.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html","title":"Gmail - Free Storage and Email from Google","persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464679910117,"hidden":false
"url":"https://www.facebook.com/","title":"Facebook - Log In or Sign Up","persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464682240507,"hidden":false
"url":"https://www.linkedin.com/","title":"World’s Largest Professional Network | LinkedIn","lastAccessed":1464682814617,"hidden":false,""
"url":"http://stackoverflow.com/","title":"Stack Overflow","persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464682191245,"hidden":false
"url":"http://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us","title":"Job Search India | one search. all jobs. Indeed","docIdentifier":5,"persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464674503732
"url":"https://www.google.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html","title":"Gmail - Free Storage and Email from Google","persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464674739300,"hidden":false
"url":"http://stackoverflow.com/","title":"Stack Overflow","persist":true,"lastAccessed":1464674774653,"hidden":false
```

**On a side note :** 
I am working on a node application. Doing something through command line would be more faster or converting it json obj and then looking for correct records ??

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gawk:

```
 awk '{if ( gensub(/.*lastAccessed":([0-9]*).*/,"\\1","g",$0) > 1464682814617) {print}}' File
```

`gensub` will extract the number after string `"lastAccessed":` and compared it with limit value and print rows if value is greater than limit value.

If `awk` or `sed` not available:

```
while read line; do 
    LASTA=$(echo "$line"| grep -o '"lastAccessed":[0-9]*'  | cut -d: -f2) ;
    if [ "$LASTA" -gt 1464682814617 ] ; then
        echo  $line
    fi
done < File
```

Comment: but gensub is external software to install , is there is command to do this by external software

Comment: `gensub` is a builtin function in `gawk` ,not an external tool.

Comment: yes we have to install gawk first then only i can use gensub

Comment: check my edit to do with just `grep` and `cut` and `bash`

Comment: very nice explanation.